# How can I render string as html in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Convert input field string in the table to the input field?

```
<%= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((string)objRow["Post"]) %>
```

On view End

```
<%= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(GetUsersList())%>
```

Code In Cs File

```
foreach (DataRow dtRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    string userpk = Convert.ToString(dtRow["user_pk"]);
    string usertypecd = Convert.ToString(dtRow["user_type_cd"]);
    string firstname = Convert.ToString(dtRow["first_name"]);
    string lastname = Convert.ToString(dtRow["last_name"]);
    string active = Convert.ToString(dtRow["active_ind"]);
    if (active == "true")
    {
        active = "< input type = 'checkbox' class='editor-active' disabled='disabled' checked='checked'>";
    }
    else {
        active = "< input type = 'checkbox' class='editor-active' disabled='disabled'>";
    }
    string phoneno = Convert.ToString(dtRow["phone_no"]);
    string phone_ext = Convert.ToString(dtRow["phone_ext"]);
    string email = Convert.ToString(dtRow["email"]);

    content += "<tr><td>"+ usertypecd+ "</td><td>" + firstname + "</td><td>" + lastname + "</td><td>" + active + "</td><td>" + phoneno + "</td><td>" + phone_ext + "</td><td>" + email + "</td><td></td></tr>";        
}

return content;
```

Result Image:

[image]

Comment: What does Asp.Net mean? Webforms, MVC, something else?

Comment: Why not use a GridView Control? It generates a html table, you can put input control in it and you can bind `ds.Tables[0]` directly to it.

Comment: Sorry, I am working on web forms. I am new to webforms I need to use a jquery data table instead of the grid view.

Comment: Since you are using `jquery datatables`, look here for how that is supposed to be done: https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Asp-WebForms you can create a `System.Web.Label` with the html text in the `Text` Property. This will then render as HTML if you add the control to your page.

Alternatively you can just dump the text into a protected/public property and use `<%= YourPropertyNameHere %>` to dump the text as it is into the page.

Personally through I recommend you build your web controls instead of string operations. For example create a `System.Web.Panel` and then add your html controls to it as you need them.

```
var pnl = new Panel();
var cb = new CheckBox();
cb.Enabled = (active == "true");
cb.Checked = cb.Enabled;
cb.CssClass = "editor-active";
pnl.Controls.Add(cb);

SomePanelInFrontCode.Controls.Add(pnl);
```

Comment: FalcoGer actually I am getting data by calling a stored procedure and try to render it on the frontend. If there is an easy solution kindly refer me.